# Issue altering values in a pandas DataFrame in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, linear-regression

I have a data set that has been loaded into a pandas `DataFrame`.
When I print `data.head()`, it looks like this.

```
G1  G2  G3  absences  failures  studytime romantic internet
0   5   6   6         6         0          2       no       no
1   5   5   6         4         0          2       no      yes
2   7   8  10        10         3          2       no      yes
3  15  14  15         2         0          3      yes      yes
4   6  10  10         4         0          2       no       no
```

I am attempting to create a linear regression model and want to convert the yes' and no's to 1s and 0s in the `romantic` and `internet` columns.

The code I used:

```
df['romantic'].replace('yes', 0)
df['romantic'].replace('no', 1)
df['internet'].replace('yes', 0)
df['internet'].replace('no', 1)
```

Did not work :( It also did not display an error of any sort.

I tried to make a linear model with `data = df[["G1", "G2", "G3", "absences", "failures", "studytime", "romantic", "internet"]]` and it showed:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'yes'
```

Even though I thought I converted them. Please help, thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert both your columns of interest, run:

```
df.romantic = (df.romantic == 'yes').astype(int)
df.internet = (df.internet == 'yes').astype(int)
```

Note also that you wrote *convert the yes' and no's to 1s and 0s*, so in
your code sample you attempt to assing the values just the opposite way.

Comment: Thanks so much! This worked but it said: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

Comment: It looks like you created your DataFrame as a **view** of another DataFrame.
This means that your *df* shares the data buffer with some another DataFrame and each attempt to modify it causes this warning.
Look at the place of your code where *df* is created.
Proably you should add *.copy()* there, to create a **separate** DataFrame
(with its own data buffer).
To confirm my suspicion, create the source *df* from scratch and run my code.
There should be no error like the one you mentioned.

Comment: Yep, I imported a complete dataset and decided to only use some of it so I did make a new dataset. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace all 'yes' with 0 and all 'no' with 1 use:

```
df.replace({'yes': 0, 'no': 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mapper = {'yes':0,'no':1}
df.loc[:,'romantic'] = df['romantic'].map(mapper)
df.loc[:,'internet'] = df['internet'].map(mapper)
```

Use map function for this job

Comment: Thanks so much for your time, this also worked. But it returned a message saying: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead. Do you know what this means?

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign it while replacing:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'romantic':['no','no','no','yes','no'], 'internet':['no','yes','yes','yes','no']})
df

df['romantic'] = df['romantic'].replace('yes', 0)
df['romantic'] = df['romantic'].replace('no', 1)
df['internet'] = df['internet'].replace('yes', 0)
df['internet'] = df['internet'].replace('no', 1)

print(df)

   romantic  internet
0         1         1
1         1         0
2         1         0
3         0         0
4         1         1
```

There are more ways to do this in Python:

[`Pandas.Series.apply Lambda`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html)

```
df['romantic'] = df['romantic'].apply(lambda x: 0 if x == 'yes' else 1)
df['internet'] = df['internet'].apply(lambda x: 0 if x == 'yes' else 1)
```

[`Numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

```
df['romantic'] = np.where(df['romantic'] == 'yes',0,1)
df['internet'] = np.where(df['internet'] == 'yes',0,1)
```

[`Pandas.Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html)

```
df['romantic'] = df['romantic'].map(dict(yes = 0, no = 1))
df['internet'] = df['internet'].map(dict(yes = 0, no = 1))
```

All yield the same result.

Answer (score -1):

```py
df.replace({'yes': 0, 'no': 1}, regex=True)
```

Try this. Replaces all occurences of 'yes' with 0 and all occurences of 'no' with 1.